# Using a Case statement to conditionally modify the number of joins

Tags: sql, dynamic

I am writing a stored procedure that uses dynamic sql.  I would like be able to conditionally add the first join criteria if The UserGroup is `<>` 'Initial'.  The following is not the actual code, it is just to show my issue

```
SELECT A FROM MyTable
   IF UserGroup <> 'Initial THEN
    INNER JOIN Table1 ON MyTable.A = Table1.A
   END
   INNER JOIN Table1 ON MyTable.B = Table1.B
   INNER JOIN Table1 ON MyTable.C = Table1.C
```

Comment: In standard SQL, each query has a fixed "shape" - the source tables are fixed, the number, type and names of columns in the result are fixed. You may be able to use some specific language extensions or dynamic SQL, but we'd need to know which SQL product you're using. Please add an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql

```
declare @Query varchar(max)

set @Query = ' SELECT A         
         FROM myTable
           '

 if (UserGroup <> 'Initial')  
   Begin
     set @Query = @Query +'INNER JOIN Table1 ON MyTable.A = Table1.A'
   End

exec(@Query)
```

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas Not necessarily. The execution plan will usually be cached too (the first time that SQL variant is run), and you can still pass parameters to exec'd query. Dynamic SQL is not *all* bad. You just have to be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how you can get the same result using outer joins:

```
SELECT A
FROM MyTable 
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 
   ON (UserGroup <> 'Initial' AND MyTable.A = T1.A) 
INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON MyTable.B = T2.B 
INNER JOIN Table1 T3 ON MyTable.C = T3.C
WHERE (UserGroup <> 'Initial' AND T1.A IS NOT NULL) OR UserGroup = 'Initial'
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be more like this:

```
select A from MyTable
inner join Table1 on 
  MyTable.A = case when UserGroup <> 'Initial' then Table1.A else MyTable.A end 
  or MyTable.B = Table1.B 
  or MyTable.C = Table1.C
```

You can change the actual `or` to `and` as required.

Comment: Just an FYI for me..Have you ever used this ? just to know if this works.

Comment: @AshutoshArya It works in MSSQL. You haven't said what DB you're using, so I can't be sure it will work with your DB, but that's it. In MS SQL, `on` can be used interchangeably with the usual `where` in joins.

Comment: @AshutoshArya Yes, but what SQL server? There's tons of SQL server software - PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQL, and many more. They're all different in some ways. Why not just try it?